# While running Jmeter test on remote machines am getting "Java Connection Reset Error"

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-3.2

While running JMETER test in Remote machines I am getting this error and i have used 1 master and 4 slaves machines.
[image: 1]

Pllease help me to resolve this error, what I need to change in Java or issue with JMETER.

For this test I have used JMETER 3.2 & Java 8 for all machines.

Comment: Please click on the link and see the image

Comment: Can Please anyone give solution for this?